# VBA - Exit Function if a timer passes 2 minutes

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got a legacy VBA function which I want to stop running if it takes longer than 3 minutes - please see below for code I have so far.

Obviously, the MsgBox only shows once function has completed but I need it to show and exit a function during.

```
        Dim startTime As Long
        startTime = GetTickCount

        Do

            If GetTickCount - startTime > 10000 Then
                MsgBox "There seems to be an issue. Please try again!"
                Exit Do
            End If

            doStuff

        Loop
```

Can anyone help me out?!

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `doStuff` the legacy VBA function?  If so, it would probably be more practical to limit its duration from within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is here for 10 seconds

```
Dim startTime As Date

        startTime = Now

        Do

            If DateDiff("s", startTime, Now) > 10 Then
                MsgBox "There seems to be an issue. Please try again!"
                Exit Do
            End If

            dostuff

        Loop
```

But this works only if duration of `dostuff` is < 10 seconds. Otherwise you must put the check into `dostuff`

Answer (score 1):

If the code is in that same sum you can just add `Exit Sub` after your msgbox.

Answer (score 0):

Check the TickCount inside the function:

```
Function doStuff()

    -your code.....
    If GetTickCount - startTime > 10000 Then
    Exit Function
    -your code.....
    -your code.....
    -your code.....

    If GetTickCount - startTime > 10000 Then
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that the Function `doStuff` is taking too long to run, then you will definitely need an `Exit` in the function itself.

Without knowing what the function itself does exactly, we cannot give specific advice for that.

But for instance, if the problem is one singular query that takes too long, then the issue cannot really be avoided. If the problem is you want it to `Exit` in between certain running portions of your function, just place a timer / Exit clause into the function where it might hang and the timer "passes 2 minutes".

By all this I mean, switch your original code around a little bit:

```
If GetTickCount - startTime > 10000 Then
    MsgBox "There seems to be an issue. Please try again!"
    Exit Function
End If
```

OR (*if your function runs some kind of loop* in itself, you could modify the `Do` in the loop itself):

```
Do While GetTickCount - startTime > 10000 
    'Code here
Loop
```