# Force a macro to stop after certain time VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a process where I use VBA to enter a webpage and download a daily file around 6 pm, although this certain file can be uploaded any time later.
Since I need to schedule automatic run for this macro because not always I will be able to run it manually (nor other person), I was thinking if there's some way to stop a macro execution after some time has passed. This is because, after the download, it should do some other things, but also the download takes a while, so if I do

```
Dir(file)
  Do While file = ""
  Do events
  ' CODE TO EXIT LOOP AFTER SOME TIME
Loop
```

The code can be hours stuck because there is no file available on the webpage, so I would like that loop to break after, let's say, 1 minute. So maybe I was thinking to catch the current time and adding the time I want it to run and then on each loop compare the current time with the time I set to stop, and then break the loop, however, I don't get how to do the time part.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51851715/1521579

Comment: Thank you, that post was the one I was looking for, I just rephrased it different and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Application.OnTime can be helpful?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Ricardo Díaz and according to this thread:
[VBA - Exit Function if a timer passes 2 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845740/vba-exit-function-if-a-timer-passes-2-minutes/51851715#51851715)

This is the code that works as a solution:

```
Dim startTime As Date

        startTime = Now

        Do

            If DateDiff("s", startTime, Now) > 10 Then
                MsgBox "There seems to be an issue. Please try again!"
                Exit Do
            End If

            dostuff

        Loop
```